# Python 'dict' object has no attribute

Tags: python

I defined some classes, I will provide class where I have issue:

```
class ImdbData:
    def __init__(self, generalResponse: ImdbGeneralResponse, tvResponse: Iterable[ImdbTvDataResponse]):
        self._generalResponse = generalResponse;
        self._tvResponse = tvResponse;
        
    @property
    def generalResponse(self):
        return self._generalResponse
    
    @property
    def tvResponse(self):
        return self._tvResponse
```

I created a service:

```
class ImdbService:
    @staticmethod
    def read(url:str, seasonNum:int = 0) -> model.imdbresponse.ImdbData:
        imdbCodeMatch = re.search("tt(\d+)", url)
        imdbCode = imdbCodeMatch.group()
        season = ""
        
        if (seasonNum > 0):
            season = str(seasonNum);
        
        requestUrl:str = f'https://mytool/{imdbCode}/{season}'
        response = requests.get(requestUrl)
        return json.loads(response.content)
```

and finally I call like:

```
sv = services.imdbsv.ImdbService.read("https://www.imdb.com/title/tt9741310/")
print(sv.generalResponse.description)
```

But I got error:

> 'dict' object has no attribute 'generalResponse'

Why ? in VS Code, when I press on F12 over `generalResponse`, the IDE redirects me to that property decorator which is good.

Still cannot figure why I got error

Comment: You're returning the result of `json.loads()` which will be a dictionary. Just because you give the type hint `-> model.imdbresponse.ImdbData` doesn't mean that's the actual return type. That just satisfies your IDE.

Comment: IDE redirects you because you specified `model.imdbresponse.ImdbData` as return type, but Python doesn't care about what is specified it still can silently return object of any type. In your case `json.loads(response.content)` returned a `dict`, just try and print it

Comment: Your `ImdbService.read` function has a type hint that says that it returns a `model.imdbresponse.ImdbData`, but it actually `json.loads(...)`. You need to create an `ImdbResponse` object from your json data before you return it.

Comment: found the conversion: `json.loads(response.content, object_hook=lambda d: SimpleNamespace(**d))`

Comment: @SnakeEyes no that isn't the conversion. Your type annotation is still wrong.

Comment: Ok, then what is the correct one?